# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while creating the object using variable

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to create Fabric.js object the following way but for some reason I am stuck.

```
var object='fabric.Circle',
     objects={};                         

objects['test1'] = new window[object]();
```

It's giving the error in 3rd line as `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` you can check the same in console.

Example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tFHj/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the object as you expect. Your code looks for the property with the name `fabric.Circle` on the window object and instead you want the `Circle` property of the `window.fabric` object. You can do this with the following code:

```
var object='fabric.Circle',
     objects={};                        

 objects['test1']=new getObj(object)(); 


function getObj(path) {
  path = path.split('.');
  var obj = window;
  while (path.length) {
    obj = obj[path.shift()];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ABIgoMiR/1/edit

Comment: thanks it works fine what is the meaning of `var obj= window` +1

Comment: You use the `obj` variable to iterate through the object chain. `var obj=window;` is the initialization, `obj=obj[..]` is the iteration. So before entering the while `obj` will be `window`. First iteration `obj` will be `window.fabric`. Second iteration `obj` will be `window.fabric.Circle`. `window` is the global object and all all global variables can be accessed as properties of the global object.

Answer (score 1):

You must parse `object`.
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/L4WyP/

```
function getProp(prop) {
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    var obj = window;

    do {
        obj = obj[parts.shift()];
    } while (parts.length);

    return obj;
}

var object = 'fabric.Circle',
    objects = {};

objects['test1'] = new (getProp(object))();
```

Comment: thanks it works fine what is the meaning of `var obj= window` +1 for your answer

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan `obj` holds the object where the property must be read. It is initialized to `window` to be able to retrieve global definitions (such as `fabric`). If this answer is what you were looking looking for, feel free to approve it.